# How does using recursion multiple times in a function work?

Tags: python, recursion

For example: the hanoi problem involves using multiple recursive calls - 'hanoi(n-1,s,b,t) and hanoi(n-1,b,t,s). However, I'm not sure what the order is of how the code is run.

Could anyone break down this code to me step by step?

```
def hanoi(n, s, t, b):
    assert n > 0
    if n ==1:
        print 'move ', s, ' to ', t
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,s,b,t)
        hanoi(1,s,t,b)
        hanoi(n-1,b,t,s)
```

Comment: first it will do the first recursive call ... all the way until it prints a move ... then it will do the second recursive call (all the way down until it prints) , and then it will run the final call ... all the way down

Comment: so will it print s to b then print s to t then print b to t based on the original function?

Comment: if n is 2 i think thats correct ...